# SAML 2.0: How to configure Assertion Consumer Service URL

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am implementing a SAML 2.0 Service Provider which uses Okta as the Identity Provider. I would like to configure the Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) URL so that the SAML 2.0 from my Service Provider app is reflected back in the assertion.

However, I am noticing that the Okta Identity Provider instead sends the SSO Endpoint configured in the Okta configuration and ignores the ACS that was actually sent. Also, I get an error perhaps the ACS from SP doesn't match the meta-data there.

If ACS URL is not the right way to send a short ID to IDP for it to reflect back in the assertion, what other mechanism can be used for this purpose.

Example:

The SAML 2.0 SAMLRequest sent by the SP app is:

assertion_consumer_service_url:
https: //host.com:port/saml/consume? entityId=N&myName=username

The configuration on Identity Provider has the meta-data:

Single Sign-on URL:
https: //host.com:port/saml/consume?entityId=N

Note that the myName changes from one request to the next, as it is our way of verifying that the response has name_id which matches the original username being sent.

Also, if there is a way for the Service Provider to let the Identity Provider assert that an SP-managed name (such as username), that would be fine for our needs. How does one specify this?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post several questions at once, it's better to post each issue as a separate question.

Answer (score 14):

In SAML, the ACS is assumed to be static for a SP. To correlate the Response with the originating AuthnRequest you should save the ID of the outgoing AuthnRequest and then use the `InResponseTo` of the received response.

The SP can add a subject to the AuthnRequest, telling the IdP what username you want to have authenticated. It's defined in section 3.4.1 in the [SAML2 Core spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As Anders Abel pointed out, the ACS is assumed to be static. However, in a development environment, it may be that a more dynamic response to different test systems is necessary.

This is my saml20-sp-remote.php that I use to respond to every SP that asks for a SSO authentication, utilizing the attribute `AssertionConsumerService` of its requests. 
I guess this is not safe for production.

simplesamlphp/metadata/saml20-sp-remote.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * SAML 2.0 remote SP metadata for SimpleSAMLphp.
 *
 * See: https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-reference-sp-remote
 */
$acs = \SAML2\Binding::getCurrentBinding()->receive()->getAssertionConsumerServiceURL();
if (!$acs) $acs = 'some_fallback_url';

$metadata['idp_identifier'] = array(
    'AssertionConsumerService' => $acs,
    'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'uid'
);
```