# Configure SSO with Zimbra using simplesaml

Tags: single-sign-on, acs, zimbra

I have installed Zimbra Network Edition v8.8.8 and it is running fine. I am trying to configure SSO using simplesaml but I am stuck at the part where I have to pass the SAML response for the SSO. Quoting from https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Authentication/SAML:

> ### Note for SAML Provider
>
> SAML Provider must POST the SAML Response at the following URL for
>   SSO:
>
> ```
> <zimbra_base_url>/service/extension/samlreceiver
> ```
>
> This SAML Consumer extension requires that the Subject Name Identifier
>   inside the SAML Assertion must be the account email address, so
>   configure the Provider accordingly.

I have tried to edit the saml20-idp-remote.php and include the Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) URL but I think the URL that I used was wrong. Or should I actually configure it in saml20-sp-remote.php file? I'm new to both SSO and Zimbra.

In the meantime I'll check out this (just found it):
[SAML 2.0: How to configure Assertion Consumer Service URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702513/saml-2-0-how-to-configure-assertion-consumer-service-url)

Appreciate all the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Zimbra SAML extension provides support for the Browser/POST Profile of SAML.

https://sites.google.com/site/ranmanicwikii/opensource/zimbra-saml-sso

Hope this helps!